# Declare a variable using an array variable substitution before the for loop

Tags: bash

I'm trying to include a reference to a variable (`B`) in another variable (`A`).  `B` gets its value from an array during a for loop, and I would hope for `A` to also get the same value, but that does not work.

```
#!/bin/bash
A=$B

ARRAY=( 1 2 3 )

for B in ${ARRAY[@]}
  do
  echo "A="$A
  echo "B="$B
done
```

How do i get `$A` to have the same value as `$B`?

Comment: Look like you are trying to alias variables or having variables as referrences. The closest you can do is variable indirection with `a='b'` then echo `${!a}` will print value of `b`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With bash `>=4` you can accomplish what you want using a `nameref`. A `nameref` is created using `declare` or `local` with the `-n` option. To create `A` as a `nameref` of `B`, you would use:

```
declare -n A=B      ## declare A as a 'nameref' of B
```

Then using your script:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -n A=B      ## declare A as a 'nameref' of B

ARRAY=( 1 2 3 )

for B in ${ARRAY[@]}
do
    echo "A="$A
    echo "B="$B
done
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ bash namerefAB.sh
A=1
B=1
A=2
B=2
A=3
B=3
```

Comment: Thanks. One more question: If I have `C="temp"` and `A=$B/$C`, then could this be extended to work in that case?

Comment: I found a solution to the question in the above comment: 
create a variable `n=0`, and then `A=${ARRAY[$n]}/$C"`.  Then you use a counter inside the loop to increase the value of `n`: `let "n=n+1"`.   That way `A` will have same value for `${ARRAY[$n]}` as `B`, and that's what I was looking for, but didn't state clearly in the question.

Comment: If you are doing that, use a C-style `for` loop, e.g. `for ((i = 0; i < ${#ARRAY[@]}; i++)); do A=${ARRAY[i]}/$C; done` (with an *indexed array*, the `$` isn't needed on the variable between `[..]`)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this answers your question the way you want but I believe A just need to be assigned in the for loop and not the beginning of the script as B doesn't have a value then.

```
#!/bin/bash
A=$B
# B is not assigned there which is why A is ""
echo "B: $B"
ARRAY=( 1 2 3 )

for B in ${ARRAY[@]}
  do
  # B is assigned here so A is assigned the same value
  A=$B
  echo "A="$A
  echo "B="$B
done
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
B:
A=1
B=1
A=2
B=2
A=3
B=3
```